# Replace cookie value to space character using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have stored some textbox values in cookies.

But if textbox blank then cookie value will "null"

I am assigning that cookie value to another textbox.But due to the null value of cookie it  showing me "null" in textbox.

I want to replace "null" with a blank space.

Comment: Difficult to say without seeing the markup for your input element.

Comment: i guess document.getElementsByName('Orders.Custom_Field_Custom7')[0] is not pointing to that text box

Comment: Do accepte answwer if you got the info you want

Answer (score 3):

Make uf of **[.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/)** function will do you task.

```
$('#youtextboxid').val(valueneedtoset);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with

```
$('input[name="Custom_Field_Custom7"]').val('11111');
```

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell based on what you've said, but I think the problem might be that you are trying to access the textbox before it has loaded. Try something like this:

```
$(function() {
    // your code here
});
```

And as others have mentioned, it would be a lot easier to just do this:

```
$('input[name="Orders\\.Custom_Field_Custom1"]').val($.cookie('UploadFile',{ path:'/'}));
```